# Rhythm game in a functional language

Tags: clojure, 2d-games, lanterna, play-clj

I want to make a vertically scrolling rhythm game (even something basic with one lane) in Clojure using [play-clj](https://github.com/oakes/play-clj) (or maybe [clojure-lanterna](https://github.com/MultiMUD/clojure-lanterna) because responsive TUI apps are neat and it works on Windows)

I don't really know how you can represent a rhythm game using immutable data and operate on said data (performance isn't really an issue as this is a toy project). What would be the idiomatic way to do so in Clojure?

I don't even need it to be able to load "beatmap" files or parse audio files, I just need help in starting out

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you want help with? There wouldn't seem to be anything especially tricky about it. Is it that you want help with clojure-lanterna or play-clj?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to structure the game loop and represent the game data idiomatically in Clojure

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered. A rhythm game is not programmed in a markedly different way than any other sort of program, so this is much like asking "How do I write a program in Clojure?" Find something more specific to ask.